# ASP.Net 1.1 JQuery Ajax Question

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services

I am trying to call a 1.1 web service.  The call seems to work, but I cannot pass any parameters.

*** Snipet 1

```
        $("#cboContacts").change(function()  {
            $.ajax(  {
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajaxhandler.asmx/ContactClick_Test",
                data: 'foo=test'
            });
        })
```

*** Snipet 2   (.asmx file)

```
Imports System.Web.Services

<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace := "http://tempuri.org/xxx/ajaxhandler")> _
Public Class ajaxhandler
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

#Region " Web Services Designer Generated Code "

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()

        'This call is required by the Web Services Designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        'Add your own initialization code after the InitializeComponent() call

    End Sub

    'Required by the Web Services Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function ContactClick_Test(ByVal strTest As String) As String
        Return "Hello World"
    End Function

End Class
```

I can get into the ContactClick_Test method if I remove the parameter  ie

Public Function ContactClick_Test() As String

This is very similar to this post - my response was deleted:

[ASP.NET 1.1 Web Services & jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586327/asp-net-1-1-web-services-jquery/7323612#7323612)

How do I pass a parameter to my WebMethod?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `data: "{ 'strTest': 'test' }"` http://elegantcode.com/2009/02/21/javascript-arrays-via-jquery-ajax-to-an-aspnet-webmethod/

Comment: In the accepted answer the line `data: {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'},` is how you pass parameters along.  the part before each `:` is the name of the parameter, the part after is the value.  I don't think order matters.

Comment: Thanks samich.  Results are the same.  The webmethod does not work if I declare a parameter.  did you read this post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586327/asp-net-1-1-web-services-jquery/7323612#7323612

Comment: If your parameter name in the server is strTest then in the client it have to be the same "{'strTest':'test'}"

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call is saying that the WebMethod expects a parameter called *foo* and its value is *test*; yet your WebMethod is declared to receive a parameter named *strTest*.

Also, your data parameter in your Ajax call is formatted wrong. Also, always include the contentType in the request. See below for the appropriate way to construct the Ajax request:

```
$("#cboContacts").change(function()  {
            $.ajax(  {
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajaxhandler.asmx/ContactClick_Test",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: "{'strTest':'test'}"
            });
  })
```

Comment: Thanks lcarus - the results are the same.  Something with the webmethod does not like paramaters in the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public static Function ContactClick_Test(ByVal strTest As String) As String
    Return "Hello World"
End Function
```

use **static** to solve your problem...

Comment: Methods cannot be declared as Static in an .asmx file.

Comment: sorry, i think you use aspx file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var test = "Test";
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              url: "ajaxhandler.asmx/ContactClick_Test",
              data:"{'strTest':'" + test+ "'}",
              dataType:"json",
              success:
               function(msg){


               },
              error:
               function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                   alert("Error.");
               }
             });
```

i think variable name is different and have to maintain same variable name in ajax and webmethod ... So check the variable

Comment: Thanks Wahidul.  It does not throw an error.  It just will not enter the method if it is declared with a parameter.

Comment: are you checked the variable name and type? follow same variable name, i mean you use foo variable in ajax json data but in webmethod used strTest variable. please use same name in both

Comment: I see what you are saying.  I changed to data: "{ 'strTest': 'Test' } ".  Still the webmethod does not like it if I declare ANY parameters  ie  (ByVal strTest As String) - Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

#### Short answer

Try `data: {'strTest':'test' }` *(notice, no quotes!)*

#### Longer answer

I'm pretty sure the issue you're running into is that you didn't copy the example from the other question correctly.  If you'll notice in the other question `data` parameter is passed in like so:

```
data: {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'}
```

You attempted to pass the data parameter like so:

```
data: 'foo=test'
```

Which I think would have worked had you named the parameter `strTest`.

```
data: 'strTest=test'
```

Icarus and Wahidul Islam had the right idea that your parameter was named wrong but they made the mistake of passing a JSON formatted string as the `data` argument as opposed to a normal JavaScript object.

```
data: "{'strTest':'test'}",   <--- this
data: {'strTest':'test'},     <--- instead of this
```

If you look inside the jQuery [source code (line 636)](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/69585ba3c7f4f49b6370f63963b7317698ead861/src/ajax.js) you'll see there's a call to the `param` method which formats the `data` argument unless it's already a string.  Since their examples pass in a string, the `param` method is never called, which causes your `POST` to be malformed, so ASP.NET doesn't recognize the parameters and the web service isn't called correctly.